# Running a web application from external network client pc

Tags: apache, server, client, dsn

I am stuck to running my web app. from external network, and also from other machine in local network
My client has a server machine (OS: windows server 2022, local machine ip xxx.xxx.0.1
, server machine dsn ip yy.yy.yy.170).

I installed the wampserver, started the web app (php, mysql, react) after creating a virtual host in apache that listens to a certain port(xxxx).

on local server machine, hitting ([www.example.org](http://www.example.org)) or (http://xxx.xxx.0.1:8029/) opens the main page and the browsing the app routes is completely smooth.
But when hitting the the browser from local network pc`s and external network clients, it opens the main page, but nothing happen. even after changing the virual host file configuration (require local changed to require all granted).

here is mu httd-vhost-conf file

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:${MYPORTxxxx}>
    ServerName www.example.org
    DocumentRoot "doc/root"
    <Directory  "doc/root/website/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require All granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
```